# Payment integration with Paytm , not able to see cart show error of Deprecated Magneto 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have install Magneto 2 with PHP Version 8.2.7 using following steps
Download a ZIP of the repository.
Unzip and open the downloaded folder.
Copy app/code/One97 folder from the Magento_V2.3+ version.
Run the command below from Magento Webstore folder:

- php bin/magento module:enable One97_Paytm
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
  Done configuration in admin
  But when access the front end cart got following error
  1 exception(s):
  Exception #0 (Exception): Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property One97\Paytm\Helper\Data::$stockRegistry is deprecated in /var/www/html/magento_multiple/app/code/One97/Paytm/Helper/Data.php on line 48
  [image]

I have added **#[AllowDynamicProperties]** but it does not work

Comment: _"I have added #[AllowDynamicProperties]"_ - not sure what you are talking about there. The error comes from PHP itself, this is nothing you could configure, AFAIK. At most you can turn deprecated warnings of via the PHP error_reporting.

Comment: Thank you, but deprecated is not warning its throws Exception and stops the execution